# Help with making NSURLConnection in a custom class

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

Hey all, I'm trying to use Yahoo's PlaceFinder to do reverse geocoding for an app I'm making. Problem is I need to use the NSURLConnection to call to my database. So I decided to make a custom class that is initialized with the user's latitude and longitude, and only store a string variable containing the state the user is in.

**Update the following code now works fine....**

Here is the .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"

@interface StateFinder : NSObject 
{
    NSString *userState;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
}

-(id)initwithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude andLongitude:(NSString *)longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userState;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "StateFinder.h"

@implementation StateFinder

@synthesize userState;
@synthesize connection;

-(id)initwithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude andLongitude:(NSString *)longitude
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        NSString *lat = latitude;
        NSString *lon = longitude;

        NSString *stateURLFinder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=%@,+%@&gflags=R&flags=J&appid=zqoGxo7k", lat, lon];

        //NSLog(stateURLFinder);

        NSURL *stateURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stateURLFinder];


        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: stateURL];

        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        [request release];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLoading");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    // Store incoming data into a string
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(jsonString);
    // Yes, this is incomplete, but I was waiting for the method to fire before going
        // any further. This will at least show me the JSON data being returned from yahoo 
        // in string format so I can output it to the console via NSLog
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [userState release];
    [connection release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This is the current code I'm using and it works fine. All I did was include the connectionDidFinishLoading and didFailWithError methods to the original code. With regards to the connection being released before it was made, I used the code above as is without the previously mentioned methods and neither didReceiveData/didReceiveResponse would hit. It wasn't until those 2 methods were included that the methods began getting called. Not sure how, not sure why, but that was the only change among all of those suggested that worked. Big thanks to @Jiva DeVoe , @XJones , @jlehr and @Aby for all the tips/hints/suggestions!

Comment: Per multiple suggestions, I commented out the release of the connection, even though it seemed to be working in other parts of my code used to make a call to my database. By commenting out the release, I'm still not hitting the didReceiveData or didReceiveResponse methods inside this class. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I advise that you definitely do not use sendSynchronousRequest.  You should always try to use asynchronous networking unless the app you're developing is a command line app without a run loop.

I suspect your problem may be that you're releasing the connection immediately, so it's never getting a chance to run.  You should add a member variable and keep it around until you've received a response or whatever.

Bonus tip:

Guessing you're probably doing this for either iOS or the Mac, and writing GUI apps.  These apps have run loops.  When you use synchronous networking like the prior answer suggests, you prevent that runloop from executing.  This means that if the request takes longer than a few seconds, your iOS app will be killed by the OS, and your Mac app will appear non-responsive.  Neither of these are good results.

Comment: Hmm, it was my understanding that didReceiveData was called immediately when the NSURLConnection was established. In my view controller that make my database call is how I have it coded above and it returns with no issues.

Comment: As far as the app, it will just run once through (the custom class is called once in the view controller's init method, and the connection within the custom class is in the init method inside the custom class as well, so it should never get called multiple times.

Comment: First, it doesn't matter if it's called multiple times.  Not sure what you're suggesting with that.  Second, WRT didReceiveData being called immediately... well, it's called as soon as the NSURLConnection gets data... but since you're releasing the NSURLConnection immediately, it's never getting a chance to run on the runloop and so you're never even attempting to make the connection.

Comment: Oh, also, HUGE problem here... not sure why I didn't see it before... your init method is totally wrong.  You need to be doing something like: if((self = [super init])) { ... all your code there ... } inside it.

Comment: OK, I edited my code to include your suggested if statement. Also, I attempted to simply comment out the releasing of the connection (worrying about the memory leak once I saw it worked) and didReceiveData still is not being called. Any thoughts on why it wouldn't be?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if maybe your runloop isn't running... maybe a background thread?  Try adding:     [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

Comment: I posted my new .m file with the code you've suggested (both the super init and the runloop check) and didReceiveData/didReceiveResponse are still not being called. Big thanks for all your help and suggestions thus far, but I'm still not able to get my desired result.

Comment: Have you checked the `NSURLConnection` instance after the line that creates to make sure it's not `nil`? Perhaps there's something wrong with the URL itself.

Comment: Well, ya got me.  Yeah, I'd check to verify it's not nil... but other than that... that code looks correct.  You must have some issue elsewhere.  Perhaps self isn't being retained long enough for the connection to complete etc... it's some issue bigger than this chunk of code you have here.

Comment: Also, for completeness sake, you can get rid of the scheduleInRunLoop line since that didn't solve the problem.  That was more a shot in the dark to see if you had some bigger issue.

Comment: I'm putting money on the idea that you're releasing this object you've created right after initializing it, just like you did with NSURLConnection before.  What's that code look like?  Where you create this object and stuff.

Comment: I had removed the scheduleRunLoop as soon as it didn't work. The code above now reflects how it is running in my program. I appreciate all your help and suggestions and am happy to report the code is now working.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a `release` message to the connection before it's had a chance to run; don't do that. With regards to JSON, the string you said was returned from the server *is* JSON. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: OK, I commented out the release (I'll worry about the memory leak later), but didReceiveData still is not being called.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the line:

```
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Once you've initialized the connection with the request it runs automatically. You have other problems as well. Your implementation of the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol is wrong. You need to incrementally add data received in `connection:didReceiveResponse` to an NSMutableData object. You can convert it to JSON in `connectionDidFinishLoading:'.

As for the memory leak, release the connection in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` or `connection:didFailWithError:` You are guaranteed to receive one but not both of them.

Everything you need to know is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)

[EDIT: added NSURLConnection code sample]

```
// Attach this to the touchUpInside event of a UIButton
// Note that all objects will be autoreleased
// Note that you can comment out any or all of the NSURLConnection delegate methods
// and the request will execute

- (IBAction)initiateRequest
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didRecieveData:(NSData *)date
{
    NSLog(@"connection:didReceiveData");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"connection:didReceiveResponse:");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading:");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connection:didFailWithError:");
}
```

Comment: @XJones , that connection line wasn't one I originally had in my code, but suggested by another user. I included it, didn't work, so I took it out, I'll edit the above code. Also, the implementations of didReceiveData and didReceiveResponse are incomplete as I was waiting for either of them to actually be called before I tried to do anything with the data.

Comment: That's fine. Is `didReceiveData` being called now? If it is, the data you receive is just a partial chunk and likely won't be a valid JSON string. You should also be getting one of `didFinishLoading` or `didFailWithError`. You should add those to help debug, perhaps it is failing with an error and you don't know it yet.

Comment: It wasn't hitting before I had that line of code in, which is why it was suggested that I include it. Anyways, I checked one last time and it still didn't hit, but then I included the two methods you suggested and now didReceiveData and didReceiveResponse are both hitting. Apparently all methods are required?

Comment: None of the methods are required by `NSURLConnection`. I have tested this myself. Also, if/when your problem is solved it would be appropriate for you to give credit to the folks that helped you, me or others. Esp if you would like continued help from folks on SO.

Comment: Apparently different programming laws apply to me. In the past I've had programs not compile because of a variable name (rockPile), code that was commented out cause my program to crash and now this. I am very grateful to all those who have made suggestions, offered advice, etc and am more than willing to give credit. Problem is none of the answers given technically made my program work besides adding those two methods, so which should I label as the correct "answer?" Also I don't have enough rep to vote up any of the answers. I'm open to any suggestions on how to give proper credit.

Comment: Well, I can assure you, Objective-C and the iOS frameworks work the same for you as for anyone. I'll add a quick code sample to this answer to show you what works. If it doesn't work in your program then you have something external affecting the run loop. The more you understand about how Obj-C works, the easier it will be for you to debug problems like this. Wrt credit, fair enough. @Jiva DeVoe gave you some good info as well.

Comment: Also, the code in your original post has been edited so I'm going from memory but the direct answer to your question is what both @Jiva DeVoe and @jlehr said. You were releasing the NSURLConnection before it had internally initiated the request. There are/were other problems with your code but they were not directly relevant to why the request wasn't running. Once you removed the release, any other reason the connection still wasn't running is/was outside of the code you posted.

Comment: @XJones I've edited the code above to reflect the code in my program that is now hitting the appropriate methods. The connection being released early was originally suggested so I commented out the release to no avail. I promise you the only suggestion that resulted in the two methods being called was adding the other fail methods you suggested. I'm still not sure which answer to deem correct, and i added special thanks to everyone who has helped me through this. Hoping nobody feels slighted, as soon as I get enough rep I'll come back and vote up all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to XJones for the suggestion. I wasn't including the two methods `didFinishLoading` or `didFailWithError` once inserted into my code, both `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData` both began to hit. Thank you all for the tips, advice and suggestions and hopefully this helps someone else out down the road.

Comment: None of the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods are required. You need to handle `connection:didFinishLoading` and `connection:didFailWithError:` to clean up properly but the NSURLConnection will perform the request regardless. I have tested this personally to verify. I also suggest you give credit (through voting and acceptance) to the folks on SO, me or others, who have spent time helping you.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why mine wouldn't work without the two methods then. Just another in the long line of programming obstacles that only seem to apply to me. Also, I'm perfectly fine with giving credit to everyone, I just didn't know which to label as the "answer" since including those two methods was the only thing that worked. Also I don't have enough "rep" to vote up any of the answers provided. :(